# Endless loop: why is this sooo endless

Tags: c

Ok so i got a small problem here. 
Don't mind the comments in the code they are there for me.

my problem is in the function. I want it to test to make sure again[0] = y or n. And if it doesn't to loop around until i enter the right number.

Now what it does: It is looping around endlessly no mater what i put in.

Did i miss something i am sure it did.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstdio>

//functions called
float wages_loop();

//start main 
int main(void)
{
    char status[10], another[10];
    char buffer[80];

    float wages, other_income, interest, dividends, test;
    int dependents;
    int single_acc = 0, mj_acc = 0, ms_acc = 0, sh_acc = 0;

    printf("Would you like to start: ");
    gets_s(another);

    while (another[0] = 'y')
    {
        //printf("What is your Status: ");
        //gets_s(status);


        wages = wages_loop();



        //printf("\n How much in Other Income. ");
        //gets_s(buffer);
        //other_income = atof(buffer);

        //printf("\n How much in interest. ");
        //gets_s(buffer);
        //interest = atof(buffer);

        //printf("\n How much in Dividends. ");
        //gets_s(buffer);
        //dividends = atof(buffer);

        //printf("\n How many Dependents. ");
        //gets_s(buffer);
        //dependents = atoi(buffer);

        printf("\n\n\t\t Your wage is: %.2f \n", wages);
        system("pause");
    } //end loop

    printf("\n\n\t\t\t Number of Singles filleing: %i \n", single_acc);

    return 0;

}//end main


float wages_loop()
{
    char again[10];
    char buffer[80];
    float wages, total_wages = 0;

    printf("\n How much in Wages. ");
    gets_s(buffer);
    wages = atof(buffer);

    total_wages = wages + total_wages;

    printf("\n Do you have any more wages. (y or n)");
    gets_s(again);

    if (again[0] != 'y' || 'n')
    {
        while (again[0] != 'y' || 'n')
        {
            printf("\n\n INCORRCT ANSWER. \n\n");
            printf("\n Do you have any more wages. (y or n)");
            gets_s(again);
        }
    }

    while (again[0] = 'y')
    {
        printf("\n Enter Wages: ");
        gets_s(buffer);
        wages = atof(buffer);

        total_wages = wages + total_wages;

        printf("\n Do you have any more wages. ");
        gets_s(again);
    }

    return total_wages;
}
```

Comment: Typo, you used assignment(`=`) should have used equality(`==`).

Comment: Small. Reproducible. Testcase.

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings and it will tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: even if you change it to == you're still not changing `another[0]` inside your loop

Comment: *Don't mind the comments in the code they are there for me.* It would be polite of you when you would remove the non-essential comments.

Comment: `gets_s(another);` --> `gets_s(another, 10);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
while (another[0] = 'y')
```

This is assignment, not equality. Change `=` to `==`

EDIT: You did it again here:

```
while (again[0] = 'y')
```

Also:

```
(again[0] != 'y' || 'n')
```

Should be

```
(again[0] != 'y' && again[0] != 'n')
```

Because `'n'` by itself will always return true

(Thanks Jonathan Henson)

**EDIT2:** As Sam i am pointed out in the comments, you're not setting `another[0]` within the loop, so it will remain infinite even if you changed the operator to `==`, add a statement to grab user input again.

**EDIT3:** As log0 points out, you can avoid this issue in the future by turning up the warning levels on your compiler.

Comment: don't forget to call out || 'n' which will always return true.

Comment: @user3255517 Your compiler should have warn you about this loop condition. You probably need to change your warning level.

Comment: i owe you guys a drink.

Comment: @AndyG In fact no. Your answer point out the problem. I point out this problem should have been warned with the proper settings. I like this comment here :) It could be part of your answer...

Comment: @log0 Your wish is my command :)